# Return array of applied functions with Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to call an Array of functions with a value and get an Array of the partially applied functions back.

My current code:

```
const my_array = pipe(flip(call), flip(map)([add, subtract]))(1)
// = [add(1), subtract(1)]
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

My goal (possibly unreasonable) would be to have a [point-free](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) alternative to the following function:

```
const bind_all = (funcs) => pipe(flip(call), flip(map)(funcs))
bind_all([add, subtract])(1)
// = [add(1), subtract(1)]
```

This seems to be similar to [juxt](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt), but returning an Array instead of a function.

---

**Update:** In response to the answers, I agree that my current code is far from readable, due to trying to force a point-free approach (with limited knowledge of existing patterns).
This question is simply trying to explore the limits of point-free design that maintains readability.

The current answers seem to indicate that this is actually unreasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but [`juxt`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt) does seem to do what you need

```
juxt([add, flip(subtract)])(1)(7); //=> [8, 6]
```

---

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, this did not capture the original requirements.  I think the following approach does.  It is similar to the one from [@naomik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183), but creating a reusable function rather than simply running inline:

```
const callAll = curry((fns, arg) => map(fn => fn(arg), fns));

const partials = callAll([add, subtract], 10); //=> [add(10), subtract(10)]
callAll(partials, 3); //=> [10 + 3, 10 - 3] => [13, 7]
```

Obviously we could write this in a way that handles multiple parameters, if we desired.  Using it once to create the partial functions, then again to apply the argument to them feels pretty elegant, too.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20callAll%20%3D%20curry%28%28fns%2C%20arg%29%20%3D%3E%20map%28fn%20%3D%3E%20fn%28arg%29%2C%20fns%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20partials%20%3D%20callAll%28%5Badd%2C%20subtract%5D%2C%2010%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5Badd%2810%29%2C%20subtract%2810%29%5D%0AcallAll%28partials%2C%203%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B10%20%2B%203%2C%2010%20-%203%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B13%2C%207%5D)**.

Comment: Interesting but `juxt([add, flip(subtract)])` returns a function, not an Array

Comment: I was misunderstanding.  It doesn't do to try to code on a phone!  Sorry about that.

Comment: Updated with a version that seems to actually *meet* the requirements.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people insist on doing everything point-free when your code ends up looking like junk - flip this, flip that. what a brainf*ck.

```
pipe(flip(call), flip(map)([add, subtract]))(1)
```

If you have `[add, subtract]` and `1` and you wish to have `[add(1), subtract(1)]` just write the damned mapping function

```
map(f => f(1), [add, subtract])
// => [add(1), subtract(1)]
```

We can see how repeating this would give us fully applied functions

```
map(f => f(1), map(f => f(1), [add, subtract]))
// => [add(1)(1), subtract(1)(1)]
// => [2, 0]
```

---

If you're that fixated on writing everything point-free, write your own combinator

```
const $ = x => f => f (x)

R.map($(1), [R.add, R.subtract])
// => [add(1), subtract(1)]

R.map($(1), R.map($(1), [R.add, R.subtract]))
// => [add(1)(1), subtract(1)(1)]
// => [2,0]
```

Comment: `map(f => f(1), [add, subtract])` is much more understandable than original solution, but to be fair that was the question: is there a better way? (yes, there is)

Comment: define "better" – *better* as in "your future self and coworkers will thank you for writing code they can read"-*better*?

Comment: `(1)(1)` is a lucky invocation here.  `R.map($(7), R.map($(1), [R.add, R.subtract]))` results in `[8, -6]` (note the negative sign) because of the confusing nature of Ramda's partial application of infix operators.

Comment: @ScottSauyet what do you mean? `R.subtract(1)(7)` (`1 - 7`) should be `-6`. I'm not sure what you're pointing out.

Comment: @naomik hmm sorry if I was not clear, I meant I agree with you. Matt was asking if there was a better way than his, and I believe yours is. And for every definition of "better" I can think of :)

Comment: @naomik: just that most people expect `subtract(1)` to be equivalent to `n => n - 1`, not `n => 1 - n`.

Comment: This answer seems needlessly harsh but beyond that, the arguments are in the wrong order: I receive the Array of functions first before the value applied to them. Scott's answer has the arguments in the correct order.

Comment: I absolutely agree with the point that one should not make a fetish over point-free.

Comment: This answer is not overly harsh.  It is hard to watch people use points-free as a hammer in search of nails... and this from someone who wrote a library in good part to make points-free easier to do in JS.  @naomik offers a useful approach, and only a smattering of snark.

Comment: True, I apologise to @naomik for reading too much into the snark. The answer does raise valid points, which is why I updated my question. I'm still learning the balance between both styles, and in this case I have erred on the pointless :)